# Logic: Combining dropdown boxes to toggle visibility

Tags: javascript, logic, toggle, visibility

I have 100 rows of data, each with 3 properties: age, location, gender.

I have 3 select boxes, to filter my data based on age, location and gender.

My function, setVisible(true) or setVisible(false), makes a row hidden or visible.

I want to filter my data, depending on what the dropdown boxes have selected.

I have set up 3 event listeners:

```
$('.age_selector').change(function() {
    for (i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        if (data[i].age == $('.age_selector').val()){
            data[i].setVisible(true);
        } else {
            data[i].setVisible(false);
        }
    }
});
$('.location_selector').change(function() {
    for (i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        if (data[i].location == $('.location_selector').val()){
            data[i].setVisible(true);
        } else {
            data[i].setVisible(false);
        }
    }
});
$('.gender_selector').change(function() {
    for (i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        if (data[i].gender == $('.gender_selector').val()){
            data[i].setVisible(true);
        } else {
            data[i].setVisible(false);
        }
    }
});
```

My problem is that the visibility only depends on the dropdown option that I selected most recently. Eg, If I have selected America as the location, then I select Males, my list shows *all* the males, regardless of location/age. How can I combine the logic so that it would be filtered to show only American Males?

Thanks

Edit:
I was hoping to have something along the lines of a counter, so instead of having

```
if (data[i].age == $('.age_selector').val()){
    data[i].setVisible(true);
}
```

I would have something like

```
if (data[i].age == $('.age_selector').val()){
    data[i].counter++;
}else{
    data[i].counter--;
}
```

And that at the very end, if the counter is above a certain value, the data would be visible. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
// Store our current selections
var age_selection, location_selection, gender_selection;

// Do the real filtering
function do_filter() {
    // For each element
    for (i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
        // If our data doesn't match one of the selections, set it to not visible
        if (age_selection != null && data[i].age != age_selection) {
            data[i].setVisible(false);
        } else if (location_selection != null && data.location != location_selection) {
            data[i].setVisible(false);
        } else if (gender_selection != null && data.gender != gender_selection) {
            data[i].setVisible(false);
        } else {
            // Otherwise, set it visible
            data[i].setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}

// When one of the selectors changes, store the selection, and call do_filter
$('.age_selector').change(function() {
    age_selection = $('.age_selector').val();
    do_filter();
});
$('.location_selector').change(function() {
    location_selection = $('.location_selector').val();
    do_filter();
});
$('.gender_selector').change(function() {
    gender_selection = $('.gender_selector').val();
    do_filter();
});
```